# Hydro on Yosemite catkin python-em

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would anyone be able to suggest why I get this error and how I could debug it to try make Hydro from source? In that directory there is `__init__py __init__.pyc locale tests`. This is at step 2.1.3 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source).

```
-- catkin 0.5.89
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/em'
CMake Error at cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python" "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/em" "--raw-errors"
  "-F"
  "/Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/catkin_generated/pkg.develspace.context.pc.py"
  "-o"
  "/Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin/lib/pkgconfig/catkin.pc"
  "/Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/em/pkg.pc.em") returned error
  code 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199637/hydro-on-yosemite-catkin-python-em/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seemed to have got around this issue by copying the file `em.py` that was just lying around in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` into the `em` folder, and renaming it to `__main__.py`

---

Originally posted by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) with karma: 83 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on 2014-12-16**:
it would be nice if i had enough rep to accept my own answer

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-26**:
Looks like you've made it now with those two question.

**Comment by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on 2015-02-27**:
not quite, it failed at about package 170/200 after a lot of painstaking modification of files in packages that were attempting to be installed. I imagine packages will be fixed up eventually to work, fingers crossed.